# Finding requests per second for distributed system - a textbook query

Tags: multithreading, resources, distributed-computing, distributed-system

Found a question in Pradeep K Sinha's book

[image]

From my understanding it is safe to assume howsoever number of threads are available. But how could we compute the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Single-threaded:**

We want to figure out many requests per second the system can support. This is represented as `n` below.

`1 second 
= 1000 milliseconds 
= 0.7n(20) + 0.3n(100)`

Since 70% of the requests hit the cache, we represent the time spent handling requests that hit the cache with `0.7n(20)`. We represent the requests that miss the cache with `0.3n(100)`. Since the thread goes to sleep when there is a cache miss and it contacts the file server, we don't need to worry about interleaving the handling for the next request with the current one.

Solving for n:

`1000
= 0.7n(20) + 0.3n(100)
= 0.7n(20) + 1.5n(20)
= 2.2n(20)
= 44n
=> n = 100/44 = 22.73`.

Therefore, a single thread can handle 22.73 requests per second.

**Multi-threaded:**

The question does not give much detail about the multi-threaded state, apart from the context switch cost. The answer to this question depends on several factors:

1. How many cores does the computer have?
2. How many threads can exist at once?
3. When there is a cache miss, how much time does the computer spend servicing the request and how much time does the computer spend sleeping?

I am going to make the following assumptions:

1. There is 1 core.
2. There is no bound on how many threads can exist at once.
3. On a cache miss, the computer spends 20 milliseconds servicing the request (e.g. checking the cache, contacting the file server, and forwarding the response to the client) and 80 milliseconds sleeping.

I can now solve for n:

`1000 milliseconds
= 0.7n(20) + 0.3n(20)`.

On a cache miss, a thread spends 20 milliseconds doing work and 80 milliseconds sleeping. When the thread is sleeping, another thread can run and do useful work. Thus, on a cache miss, the thread only uses the CPU for 20 milliseconds, whereas when the process was single-threaded, the next request was blocked from being serviced for 100 milliseconds.

Solving for n:

`1000 milliseconds
= 0.7n(20) + 0.3n(20)
= 1.0n(20)
= 20n
=> n = 1000/20 = 50`.

Therefore, a multi-threaded process can handle 50 requests per second given the assumptions above.